# Ninject Binding Generic and Specific Interfaces to Same Implementation

Tags: .net, vb.net, ninject

Is there a simpler way to have Ninject always use the most specific interface when injecting?

For example, I have a generic repository interface:

```
Public Interface IRepository(Of TKey, TEntity As {Class, IEntityKey(Of TKey)})
    Sub Save(entity As TEntity)
    Sub Delete(entity As TEntity)
End Interface
```

I then have a more specific interface for certain entities:

```
Public Interface ISpecificEntityRepository
    Inherits IRepository(Of Integer, SpecificEntity)

    Function DoSomethingSpecial() As SpecificEntity
End Interface

Public Class SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl
   Inherts RepositoryImpl(of Integer, SpecificEntity)
   Implements ISpecificEntityRepository
        Overrides Sub Save(entity As TEntity)
          ' Do something specific here for this entity
        End Sub

        Function DoSomethingSpecial() As SpecificEntity Implements ISpecificEntityRepository.DoSomethingSpecial 
          ' Do something else
        End Function
End Class
```

This interface inherits from the generic repository interface so it can always be used in its place.

Now in my Ninject kernel I have the bindings:

```
' The generic repository bindings for all entities
Bind(GetType(IPersistRepository(Of ,))).To(GetType(Repository(Of ,)))

' Specific bindings
Bind(Of IRepository(Of Integer, SpecificEntity)).To(Of SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl)()
Bind(Of ISpecificEntityRepository).To(Of SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl)()
```

As you can see the specific bindings had to be bound twice. **Is there a way to make Ninject always use the most specific binding so all I would need is:**

```
 ' The generic repository bindings for all entities
Bind(GetType(IPersistRepository(Of ,))).To(GetType(Repository(Of ,)))

' Specific bindings
Bind(Of ISpecificEntityRepository).To(Of SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl)()
```

It could then figure out that `ISpecificEntityRepository` inherits from `IRepository` and use the `SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl` for both without explicitly binding it twice?

The reason I need this is because I want my code to always use the most specific implementation regardless if the code wants the generic interface injected or the specific one. For example a method in the generic interface may be overridden for certain entities in the specific one and I always want to use the specific version.

These should be reference the same implementation:

```
Dim x as ISpecificEntityRepository               ' == SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl
Dim y as IRepository(Of Integer, SpecificEntity) ' == SpecificEntityRepositoryImpl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both bindings are required but you could make use of the [convention extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) to cut down on your work.

Something along the lines of (i'm using C# syntax because i'm not familiar with VB.net, sorry):

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRepository))
            .BindWith<RepositoryBindingGenerator>());

public class RepositoryBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        // todo: using reflection, get the specific interface type and get T of IRepository<T>
        // then create a binding for both like:

        yield return bindingRoot.Bind(closedGenericRepositoryInterface).To(type);
        yield return bindingRoot.Bind(specificRepositoryInterface).To(type);
    }
}
```